# bazel WORKSPACE file not behaving as documented?

Tags: bazel

Consider the following hierarchy:

```
WORKSPACE
foo/
  BUILD
  foo.sh
bar/
  BUILD
  bar.sh
```

Where, e.g., `foo/BUILD` contains

```
sh_binary(
  name = "foo",
  srcs = ["foo.sh"],
)
```

and similarly for `bar/BUILD`. As expected, `bazel cquery //...` prints:

```
INFO: Analyzed 2 targets (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured).
INFO: Found 2 targets...
//bar:bar (a5d130b)
//foo:foo (a5d130b)
```

According to https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/build-ref.html, *"Bazel ignores any directory trees in a workspace rooted at a subdirectory containing a WORKSPACE file (as they form another workspace)."*

Therefore, if I `touch bar/WORKSPACE`, I should expect `bar` to no longer be part of my workspace, and its contents should be ignored by bazel. Why, then, do I still get the same query results?

```
$ ls bar
BUILD  WORKSPACE  bar.sh

$ bazel cquery //...
INFO: Analyzed 2 targets (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured).
INFO: Found 2 targets...
//bar:bar (a5d130b)
//foo:foo (a5d130b)
```

Bazel version is 3.7.0.

Comment: Could this be caching? What happens after `bazel clean --expunge`?

Comment: No, I had already checked that. Maybe I'm misunderstanding what the documentation is saying, but I can't figure out what *else* it could be saying that would make sense. If it means that something starting *below* a directory with a WORKSPACE will not keep going up to find a WORKSPACE above it, then it's very badly worded.

Comment: I can get the desired effect by listing `bar` in a `.bazelignore`, but the question of what the documentation actually remains unanswered.

Answer (score 1):

I answered this [in the slack thread the author created](https://bazelbuild.slack.com/archives/CA31HN1T3/p1607615214079800), but for posterity, the confusion here was due to the author's interpretation (and possibly poor verbiage) in the documentation.

---

A `WORKSPACE` file alone doesn't "instantiate" or "define" a wholly separate workspace, as the author of this question assumed -- as such, Bazel won't treat that subdirectory any differently from any other package. Instead, the workspace needs to be defined as an "external repository" -- that is to say, "external" to the parent workspace, not necessarily a repository whose source code lives somewhere else.

You can do this using [`local_repository`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/3.5.0/be/workspace.html#local_repository) like so:

**`WORKSPACE`**

```
local_repository(
    name = "bar_workspace_name",
    path = "bar",
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I may be projecting an actual behavior of bazel into interpreting the intended meaning of the sentence when I suppose the "ignoring" it speaks of goes in the other direction not descending into nested directories, but crawling up towards root. Essentially...

If you have that `bar/WORKSPACE` file, it does not change the behavior when looking at it from `bar/`'s parent and `//bar` still appears as package in that workspace.

However, it impact the behavior should you run `bazel` with `bar/` for its working directory. As it tries to find the workspace root it stops `WORKSPACE` therein `bar/` becomes its own `//` in that case (and by extension its parent is not accessible as part of the same workspace).

Or in practical terms... try the same thing:

```
bazel cquery //...
```

but in bar:

```
(cd bar/ && bazel cquery //... )
```

Once with and once without `bar/WORKSPACE`.